# asp.net core sql where not exist in list

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I have a list of strings that is pulled from one server's database.
I need to use that list to pull all records from another database that are not in the above list.

> list{"apple","grape","orange"}
>
> database: grape, pear, orange, coconut

want to pull in a linq query: pear and coconut

tried `_context.fruit.where(f => !f.name.Contains(fruitList))`
but contains is saying it only works with char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.Contains` on the `List<T>` passing in the `string` value of `f`:

```
_context.fruit.Where(f => !fruitList.Contains(f.name));
```